# Use of ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator with my style

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I've followed [those instructions](http://www.limecreativelabs.com/actionbarsherlock-y-viewpagerindicator-la-pareja-perfecta/) and I've created `MyStyle` with [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), but my style is not working, I can't see my colors.

I have a `styles_mystyle.xml`with

```
<style name="Theme.Mystyle" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
```

and in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    //...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Mystyle" >
```

So I don't know where is the problem. Can you help me? My code is exactly the same as the one in previous links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style generator creates a theme for ActionBar tabs. The ViewPager looks similar but requires a different set of defined styles. You can find examples for the ViewPagerIndicator styles here:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/values/styles.xml

Alternatively, you can use the styles created from the style generator by using ActionBar tabs instead of the ViewPagerIndicator.

[VERY Basic actionbarsherlock tabs with fragments: FragmentTransaction is null in the onTabSelected() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073850/very-basic-actionbarsherlock-tabs-with-fragments-fragmenttransaction-is-null-in)

More information on tabs vs title strips can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html